# How to convert ascii encoded hash to hex encoded one?

Tags: c++, encoding, ascii, sha1

So I am using [this hash hashing code](https://github.com/vog/sha1/blob/master/sha1.hpp) to genrate a SHA1 hash. And it the hash function returns a `std::string` which is ASCII encoded and so the hash takes up 40 bytes of memory. And I need to store the hash in 20 byte(and 40 hex character) with hex encoding. How is it done?

Comment: Get two character, convert them to an `uint8_t`, store in a vector. Continue with the next two characters, and so on until you have converted all.

Comment: Also note that decimal, octal or hexadecimal are just ways to present integer values. In the computer they're all stored in binary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the `final` method there is some code which writes the `digest` array as a hex string.

```
inline std::string SHA1::final()
{
    ...

    /* Hex std::string */
    std::ostringstream result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(digest) / sizeof(digest[0]); i++)
    {
        result << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8);
        result << digest[i];
    }

    /* Reset for next run */
    reset(digest, buffer, transforms);

    return result.str();
}
```

To get a binary string instead simply replace this code with binary I/O

```
inline std::string SHA1::final()
{
    ...

    /* Binary std::string */
    std::ostringstream result;
    result.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(digest), sizeof digest);

    /* Reset for next run */
    reset(digest, buffer, transforms);

    return result.str();
}
```

Note, as always when writing multibyte integers in binary, there is a potential endianess issue here.